# Injected remix is using metamask's private key?

Tags: web3js, remix, metamask, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy

When I want to deploy smart contract by hardhat i need to put the private key ,is there any way to deploy smart contract like remix do in injectedweb3 (without using private key )?

how remix can deploy smart contract without know the private key or it get it when I sign by meta mask?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect your Metamask to Remix, Remix will use the accounts in Metamask. Metamask has the private keys for the accounts and simply allows Remix to utilize the accounts, but never gives out the private keys anywhere.

If you want to, you can connect your Metamask to your local running Hardhat network by fiddling with Metamask network settings. But usually Hardhat is meant for deployment and unit tests, where the connection is not given to external user interfaces.

Comment: thanks for your answer , my problem is that : i have web app so i want the user  to deploy his smart contract with his wallet ,how i can do that ?

Comment: Then the user should use his own wallet, such as Metamask. Your website should have code which prompts the wallet to submit the deployment transaction.

Comment: ok, deploy process is need private key or only signe? cause hardhat when you want to deploy it need privatekey ? like this code :                                                                                 const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, alchemyProvider);                                         const helloWorldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, contract.abi, signer);

Comment: Please browse for existing answers or try to read through the documentation. Or if that doesn't help, feel free to post a new question.